# mirroring SourceForge BZR branch on Launchpad

Tags: bazaar, mirroring, sourceforge, launchpad

I am trying to have Launchpad mirror a Bazaar branch on SourceForge but failing. Is it at all possible? The Launchpad shows this log for the process:

> ```
> 2012-02-26 12:44:20 INFO Starting job.
> 2012-02-26 12:44:20 INFO Getting exising bzr branch from central store.
> 2012-02-26 12:44:20 INFO [chan bzr SocketAsChannelAdapter] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
> 2012-02-26 12:44:20 INFO Invalid URL: bzr://log4cplus.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzrroot/log4cplus/trunk/
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please file a bug against the Launchpad project about this.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the patch adding the bzr:// scheme there.